# unexpected input value; log10 failed

Tags: c, visual-studio

When I write:

```
printf("%f; ", massive[i]);
```

Where:

```
double** InputSystemOfLinearEquationsByFile(FILE* file) {
    char* inputc = (char*)malloc(quiteenoughelements * sizeof(char));
    int thenumberofvaribles = 0;
    int thenumberofequations = 0;
    if (fscanf(file, "%s", inputc) == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }
    thenumberofvaribles = atoi(inputc);
    if (thenumberofvaribles <= 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fscanf(file, "%s", inputc) == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }
    thenumberofequations = atoi(inputc);
    if (thenumberofequations <= 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
double** answer = (double**)malloc(thenumberofequations*sizeof(double*));
for (int i = 0; i < thenumberofequations; i++) {
    answer[i] = (double*)malloc((thenumberofvaribles + 1)*sizeof(double));
}
for (int i = 0; i < thenumberofequations; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < thenumberofvaribles; j++) {
        if (fscanf(file, "%s", inputc) == EOF) {
            return NULL;
        }
        answer[i][j] = atof(inputc);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < thenumberofequations; i++) {
    if (fscanf(file, "%s", inputc) == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }
    answer[i][thenumberofvaribles] = atof(inputc);
}
free(inputc);
return answer;
}

    void SwapStrokes(double** matrix, const unsigned int stroke1index, const unsigned int stroke2index) {
    double* temp = matrix[stroke1index];
    matrix[stroke1index] = matrix[stroke2index];
    matrix[stroke2index] = temp;
    temp = NULL;
}

unsigned char ZeroCheck(double** matrix, const unsigned int currentstroke, const unsigned int currentcolumn, const unsigned int numberofequations) {
    int numberofnotzerocolumn = currentstroke;
    while ((fabs(matrix[numberofnotzerocolumn][currentcolumn]) < accuracy) || (matrix[numberofnotzerocolumn][currentcolumn] != matrix[numberofnotzerocolumn][currentcolumn])) {
        numberofnotzerocolumn++;
        if (numberofnotzerocolumn == numberofequations) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (numberofnotzerocolumn != currentstroke) {
        SwapStrokes(matrix, currentstroke, numberofnotzerocolumn);
    }
    return 0;
}

void JordanException(double** matrix, const unsigned int currentstroke, const unsigned int currentcolumn, const unsigned int numberofvars, const unsigned int numberofequations) {
    int optionalcolumn = 0;
    int optionalstroke = 0;
    for (optionalstroke = 0; optionalstroke < currentstroke; optionalstroke++) {
        for (optionalcolumn = 0; optionalcolumn < currentcolumn; optionalcolumn++) {
            matrix[optionalstroke][optionalcolumn] -= matrix[optionalstroke][currentcolumn] * matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] / matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
        }
        optionalcolumn++;
        for (optionalcolumn; optionalcolumn <= numberofvars; optionalcolumn++) {
            matrix[optionalstroke][optionalcolumn] -= matrix[optionalstroke][currentcolumn] * matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] / matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
        }
    }
    for (optionalstroke = currentstroke + 1; optionalstroke < numberofequations; optionalstroke++) {
        for (optionalcolumn = 0; optionalcolumn < currentcolumn; optionalcolumn++) {
            matrix[optionalstroke][optionalcolumn] -= matrix[optionalstroke][currentcolumn] * matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] / matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
        }
        optionalcolumn++;
        for (optionalcolumn; optionalcolumn <= numberofvars; optionalcolumn++) {
            matrix[optionalstroke][optionalcolumn] -= matrix[optionalstroke][currentcolumn] * matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] / matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
        }
    }
    for (optionalcolumn = 0; optionalcolumn < currentcolumn; optionalcolumn++) {
        matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] /= matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
    }
    optionalcolumn++;
    for (optionalcolumn; optionalcolumn <= numberofvars; optionalcolumn++) {
        matrix[currentstroke][optionalcolumn] /= matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn];
    }
    for (optionalstroke = 0; optionalstroke < numberofequations; optionalstroke++) {
        matrix[optionalstroke][currentcolumn] = 0.;
    }
    matrix[currentstroke][currentcolumn] = 1.;
}

double* JordanMethod(double** matrix, const unsigned int numberofvars, const unsigned int numberofequations) {
    if (numberofvars > numberofequations) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        unsigned int currentcolumn = 0;
        unsigned int currentstroke = 0;
        while ((currentcolumn < numberofvars) && (currentstroke < numberofequations)) {
            if (ZeroCheck(matrix, currentstroke, currentcolumn, numberofequations) == 1) {
                return NULL;
            }
            JordanException(matrix, currentstroke, currentcolumn, numberofvars, numberofequations);
            currentstroke++;
            currentcolumn++;
        }
        double* answer = (double*)malloc(numberofvars * sizeof(double));
        for (currentstroke = 0; currentstroke < numberofvars; currentstroke++) {
            if ((fabs(matrix[currentstroke][numberofvars]) < accuracy) || (matrix[currentstroke][numberofvars] != matrix[currentstroke][numberofvars])){
                matrix[currentstroke][numberofvars] = 0.;
            }
            answer[currentstroke] = matrix[currentstroke][numberofvars];
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

    void WriteMassive(double* massive, unsigned int numberofelements, FILE* file) {
    if ((massive != NULL) && (file != NULL)){
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberofelements; i++) {
            fprintf(file, "%f; ", massive[i]);
        }
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double* matrixa = NULL;
    double** matrix = NULL;
    FILE* file;
    FILE* output;
    file = fopen("File.txt", "r");
    matrix = InputSystemOfLinearEquationsByFile(file);
    matrixa = JordanMethod(matrix, 4, 4);
    WriteMassive(matrixa, 4, output);
    fclose(file);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My file has got:

```
4
4
2 -1 5 7
3 3,5 4 -5
-7 -3 7,2 5,3
4 3 2,1 -3,5
```

I face this bug, when i=0:

```
> Debug Assertion Failed! Program: ...ConsoleApplication1.exe File:
> minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\cfout.cpp Line: 126 Expression:
> ("unexpected input value; log10 failed, 0)
```

What should I do?
P.s. While debugging I move cursed to massive[i] and visual studio show that it has normal value (something like 6.29...).

Comment: What is its value (try `%a` or a debugger)?

Comment: How is `massive` declared?

Comment: "_Where massive is massive of double._" -- What? Did you mean array?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. My crystal ball says that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you're accessing an out-of-bounds element, or an uninitialized element ...

Comment: @CoolGuy I guess he meant _array of double_

Comment: Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would suspect that `massive[i]` is out of range (i.e. too large) for a double. What type is `massive`? You should probably be using a different formatting statement for this type.

Comment: Where do you set massive[0] to something? If it is not initialized to something after you allocate it then it will be garbage data when you try to printf it.

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong in the posted code. Create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I've tried my code on VS 2013 (instead of 2015) and... It worked! Idk how it works, maybe it just problem with my computer.

Comment: Be warned that "it appears to work elsewhere" is also symptom of **undefined behavior**. If this code is supposed to be included in something relatively important (say, a nuclear reactor core temperature safety system, or a gamma laser controller in a cancer treatment center) I urge you to check again. Try `valgrind` or something similar.